# Using <%@ Assembly %> reference without CopyLocal

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to write a standalone ASPX page (no codebehind) for reasons I won't get into.  So I want to have some functions declared in the page.  But those functions need to reference assemblies that aren't generally referenced by ASPX pages.  This means that I need an <%@ Assembly %> reference, as detailed here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d864zc1k.aspx

And it all works fine if I have my reference to the assembly set to CopyLocal = true.  However, it is in my GAC, so I don't want to set it to copy local.  But if I don't have the DLL in my /bin folder, the page does not compile due to a bad reference.

What do I have to do to get the <%@ Assembly %> declaration to work against an assembly in the GAC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically assemblies that are in the GAC are referenced in the web.config.  Is your assembly referenced in the system.web -> compliation -> assemblies section?  If not, adding it should resolve your issue.